# Running framework compiled in Swift 4.0 in Xcode 9.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I recently updated Xcode from 9.0 to 9.1. My project has an external framework created by a business partner which was compiled in Swift 4.0. When I try and run the project, I get the following error thrown by the import of the external framework:

```
Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.2
```

I understand this problem because Xcode 9.1 uses Swift 4.0.2, however, I am curious if there is anyway to compile this framework now that the Swift versions are incompatible. I tried changing the `Swift Language Version` variable in the Build Settings to `4.0` however, this made no change. I also don't see an option for 4.0.2 in this list so I am assuming when selecting 4.0 it defaults to 4.0.2?

Is there anyway I can compile this lib, or do I need to wait for them to release an update which was compiled in 4.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like:
In cocoapods separate swift 3.0.2 / 4 / 4.0.2 libraries

```
swift_32 = [<swift 3.0.2 libs>]
swift4 = [<swift 4 libs>]
swift_42 = [<swift 4.0.2 libs>]

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    swift_version = nil

    if swift_32.include?(target.name)
      swift_version = '3.2'
    end

    if swift4.include?(target.name)
      swift_version = '4.0'
    end

    if swift_c42.include?(target.name)
      swift_version = '4.0'
    end
  end
end
```

May be it will help you